# Align leads to poor result

Tags: equations, align

I have two `align` environments which do not quite lead to a good looking result, and I don't know why. To the best of my knowledge, I did not alter anything about the alignment, and the problem also occurs when I copy the equations in a completely empty document.

**How can I achieve a the "right", aesthetically pleasing typesetting of those equation?**

**Right Align**

I do not understand why the rightmost term is aligned to the right. And I also think that the position of the `=` is wrong.

```
\begin{align}
A \qquad &\longrightarrow \qquad B &= C \\
AA \qquad &\longrightarrow \qquad BB &= ABCDE 
\end{align}
```

[image]

**Huge Space**

I'm not sure why it introduces such a huge space before the rightmost term.

```
\begin{align}
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
b
\end{bmatrix}
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
C + D
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you shouldn't use hspace commands within align environments.

Answer (score 1):

The third column  with =C is right aligned but you want it left aligned so put it in the fourth column so use `&&=C`  It might also might look better without the `\qquad` which is forcing the arrows to have excessive space.

Comment: "The third column is..." - Is that a general definition in LaTeX, or is there a specific reason for that inside my code?

Comment: it's a general feature of AMS alignments which are designed for `a=b    c=d`  displays so right align to the first =, left align to the =, right align to the second =, left align to the second =.